# Direct proof square

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation, divisibility

$4\mid 4$$k^2$

**Concerns:**

Is this question answered to the best of its ability or could it use more explanation. 
Am I missing any steps

Comment: I'm not sure what the "$4\mid 4k$" part is, but the first two lines look good. If you want to tighten it up, you can get rid of the "If $c$ is even then $c^2$ is even part" and just start with "We can write $c=2k$ with $k\in\Bbb N$," then continue as you do.

Comment: Also, you can allow $k$ to be any integer, not necessarily a positive integer (i.e., $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ rather than $k\in\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: @Dave thanks for the edits. Would love to know how you turned c^2 <----not into that. It's my first day on here. I'm going to check if we have to use "If"(p) and "then"(q) when answering Proofs for conditional Statements.

Comment: @Bertrand Wittgenstein's Ghost: Multiple of $4$ usually means $4x$, where $x$ is an _integer_, unless the domain for $x$ is otherwise specified, or implied from the context.

Comment: @quasi, Yes, you are correct. My mistake.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost totally enjoyed your comment. Those symbols are beyond the knowledge we have been currently provided. I'll let you know when I am able to start using those symbols. I know $\cup \cap$

Comment: @DeNel: As Dave noted in the first comment, the line "If $c$ is even then $c^2$ is even" should be omitted. You never used it. Instead, start with "Assume $c$ is even". The natural next line would then be "Then $c=2k$, for some integer $k$".

Comment: @DeNel: Also, your final line "$4|4k$" is possibly a typo. While it's not an incorrect statement, it doesn't directly relate to the conclusion. The suggested replacement line would be: "$4|4k^2$".

Comment: @quasi Thanks for noticing that. $4\mid k^2$ is what it should be.

Comment: @DeNel: Feel free to edit your post to improve it or fix errors.

Comment: @DeNel if you want to see how I formatted some math text, you can right click on the part you want, then go to "show math as" then "TeX commands" and it'll show you what I typed. For more info, see here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 4):

The idea is there, but if you want to be more formally correct, notationwise and structurewise:

Suppose $c$ is even.

Then $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $c=2k$. (definition of even, or $2|c$).

Then for that same $k$: $c^2 = 2k \cdot 2k = 4k^2$, so $\exists l \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $c^2 = 4l$ (namely $l=k^2$) so that by definition $4|c^2$.

Done: we started with the assumption $c$ is even and ended with the desired conclusion $4|c^2$ using just definitions and standard arithmetic facts.